# How to rename the log files which will create in rotatingFileHandler after exceeding maxBytes to current datetime.log?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to override rollOver() of rotatingFileHandler so that log files name will be current date time.log?

I am new to Python programming.

Code:

```
def logger(self , inputStr):

    dateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S')

    fileName = 'log-'+dateTime+'.log'
    Path = path+'/'+fileName

    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    #logger = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s')         
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(Path, maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    for i in range(1000000):
        logger.debug("This is test log line %s" % i)
```

Comment: Please attach some sample code from your program so we can modify it in context.

Comment: check out the sample code please @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8022336/riscnotcisc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the doRollover() is override to have backup file names as current datetime.log 
**myRotatingFileHandler.py**

```
import datetime 
import os
import sys
import logging
from logging.handlers import BaseRotatingHandler
import time

class myRotatingFileHandler(BaseRotatingHandler):
def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=0):
    dateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S')

    filename = filename +'/log-'+dateTime+'.log'
    if maxBytes > 0:
        mode = 'a'
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
    self.maxBytes = maxBytes
    self.backupCount = backupCount

def doRollover(self):
    dateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S')
    #fileName = 'log-'+dateTime+'.log'
    df = ''
    if self.stream:
        self.stream.close()
        self.stream = None
    if self.backupCount > 0:
        for i in range(self.backupCount - 1, 0, -1):
            sf = self.baseFilename+'/'+'log-'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S') + '.log'
            df = self.baseFilename+'/'+'log-'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S') + '.log'
            if os.path.exists(sf):
                if os.path.exists(df):
                    os.remove(df)
                os.rename(sf, df)
        wkspFldr = os.path.dirname(self.baseFilename)
        df = wkspFldr+'/'+'log-'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S') + '.log'
        print 'LOG FILE ---> ',df
        if os.path.exists(df):
            os.remove(df)
        if os.path.exists(self.baseFilename):
            os.rename(self.baseFilename, df)
    if not self.delay:
        self.stream = self._open()

def shouldRollover(self, record):
    if self.stream is None:                 
        self.stream = self._open()
    if self.maxBytes > 0:                   
        msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
        self.stream.seek(0, 2)  #due to non-posix-compliant Windows feature
        if self.stream.tell() + len(msg) >= self.maxBytes:
            return 1
    return 0
```

This is the .py code where we have logger function
**config.py**

```
import logging
import os
import datetime
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import time
from subprocess import call
from time import gmtime, strftime
import re
import logging.handlers

import myRotatingFileHandler

path = ''
Interval = ''
Value = 0

class config:
def __init__(self, givenPath, interval, value):
    global path
    global Interval
    global Value
    path = givenPath
    Interval = interval
    Value = value

def remove_file_by_days(self):
    now = time.time()
    cutoff = now - (value * 86400)
    files = os.listdir(path)
    file_path = os.path.join(path)

    for xfile in files:
        filePath = file_path + xfile
        if os.path.isfile(filePath):
            t = os.stat(filePath)
            c = t.st_ctime
            if c < cutoff:
                print 'removing file...'
                print filePath
                os.remove(filePath)

def remove_file_by_hours(self):
    dir_to_search = os.listdir(path)
    for file in filenames:
        curpath = os.path.join(path, file)
        file_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
        if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(hours = Value):
            print 'removing file...'
            print curpath
            os.remove(curpath)

def remove_file_by_minutes(self):
    dir_to_search = os.listdir(path)
    for file in dir_to_search:
        curpath = os.path.join(path, file)
        file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
        if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(hours = Value/60 ):
            print 'removing file...'
            print curpath
            os.remove(curpath)

def logger(self , inputStr):
    dateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S')
    fileName = 'log-'+dateTime+'.log'
    Path = path
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler = myRotatingFileHandler.myRotatingFileHandler(Path, maxBytes=1024000*10, backupCount=5)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    for i in range(1000000):
        logger.debug("This is test log line %s" % i)

def debug(self, inputStr):
    if Interval == 'days':
        self.remove_file_by_days()
    if Interval == 'hours':
        self.remove_file_by_hours()
    if Interval == 'minutes':
        self.remove_file_by_minutes()
    self.logger(inputStr)
```

The calling main 
**logMain.py**

```
import logging
import os
import sys
import config
from config import config

if __name__ == '__main__':
obj = config('/var/www/cgi-bin/pythonPractice/test/','minutes', 2)
obj.debug('abc')
```

**Overall this program does removing of log files form the given path according to number of days, number of hours and number of minutes. And creates the log files with name current datetime.log, if the log file exceeds 10 mb it will create other log file with name current datetime.log.**